# Why is the value from dropdownlist not selected/checked when using "Select2.js"?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, bootstrap-5

**1-Explaination**

I am using select2 to filter a dropdown list.

(Tools used : Bootstrap 5 & .Net 7.0 Core)

After selecting the client name, i click submit.

Then i get an error that the 'clientId' is null (No client id has been selected).

**2-Question**

What is wrong with this code?

**3-The full code**

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="max-width:500px;position:relative;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form id="Create" method="post" asp-page-handler="Create">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                                <div class="form-group p-0">
                                    <label asp-for="Presentation.PreDate" class="border-0 m-0" style="max-height:20px;font-size:70%;">Date</label>
                                    <input asp-for="Presentation.PreDate" class="form-control font-weight-bold fw-bold text-primary" style="font-size:80%;"
                                           id="predate" type="text" readonly />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Presentation.PreDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>                                   
                                <div class="form-group p-0">
                                     <label asp-for="Presentation.NdeId" class="border-0 m-0" style="max-height:20px;font-size:70%;">Client</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <select asp-for="Presentation.KliId" class="form-control text-primary font-weight-bold fw-bold form-select client" name="client" asp-items="ViewBag.KliId"
                                                    data-placeholder="--- Client ---" id="client" style="font-size:80%;">   
                                            </select>
                                </div>
                                <partial name="_BtnSavePopupPartial" />
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**The javascript part**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.client').select2({
         width: '100%', 
        dropdownParent: $('#addModal')
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using,

```
name="client"
```

So you should catch the value on the request as `client` not `clientId`.